# Join two tables in one table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Good evening,

I have an issue trying to find a solution to join two tables :

For example I have

Table 1 :

```
Date  | Item
12/03 | aaaa
12/03 | aaaa
14/03 | bbbb
14/03 | aaaa
15/03 | cccc
```

Table 2 :

```
Date  | Item2
11/03 | aaaa
12/03 | aaaa
13/03 | bbbb
14/03 | aaaa
15/03 | cccc
```

I want to do a count to have this

```
Date  | Count(Item1) | Count(Item2)
11/03 | 0            | 1
12/03 | 2            | 1
13/03 | 0            | 1
14/03 | 2            | 1
15/03 | 1            | 1
```

I have tried this so far, but it doesn't seems to work, it only give me the commun dates :

```
SELECT F.DATE, COUNT(T1.Item1), COUNT(T2.Item2) FROM TABLE1 
T1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.date=T2.date

Date  | Count(Item1) | Count(Item2)
12/03 | 2            | 1
14/03 | 2            | 1
15/03 | 1            | 1
```

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: you need a `group by` clause as well.

Comment: @MarcB Can we have two group by ?

Comment: no, only one `group by` statement, but it CAN have mutiple fields/values to group on. `group by a group by b` is wrong, `group by a,b` is correct. You only need to group by the date, however.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB it seems to work when adding a group by. But the question is that when I want to Select a Date, how to say select commun dates... For example if I Select T1.Date, it will only give me Table 1 dates, same as T2... It will not give me both dates

Comment: you probably don't want a join. join is for related records, a parent/child relationship. you've got two tables that only share a common TYPE of record, but not necessarily directly related. you'd want do a subquery type thing. `select count stuff from (select * from A union all select * from B) group by date field`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? Please use the appropriate tag so you don't get answers that won't work for you.

Comment: Barmar, I am using MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In the below SQL, the first inline view is computing all the counts at date level and same applies with second query. By combining the results of left join and right join between these two inline views we can combine all the common and uncommon results from both tables as you described.


        SELECT Date,
               Item1,
               Item2 
          FROM
             (  
                SELECT T1.Date AS Date,
                       COUNT(  T1.Item  ) AS Item1,                     
                       COUNT(  T2.Item  ) AS Item2  
                  FROM Table1 t1
                LEFT JOIN
                       Table2 t2  
                    ON t1.date = t2.date  
                GROUP BY t1.Date              
          UNION              
                SELECT T2.Date AS Date,
                       COUNT( T1.Item ) AS Item1,
                       COUNT( T2.Item ) AS Item2
                  FROM Table2 t2
                LEFT JOIN
                       Table1 t1   
                    ON t2.date = t1.date
                GROUP BY t2.Date
              ) A
         ORDER BY Date        
        ;
```

**SQL Fiddle Implementation :-**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b872/14

Comment: It doesn't work, since that both columns are named date. If I select X.date I only have dates in X.

Comment: Column 'Date' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Try now... I added the alias

Comment: @SOaddict your first statement needs to be SELECT COALESCE(X.Date,Y.DATE) DATE  like this to display all the dates

Comment: @SagarShelke any Idea how to test it in Mysql, doesn't work for me

Comment: @SOaddict #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: You are right... there is no full outer join in mysql.. let me rewrite the sql...

Comment: @SOaddict It only give me the commun dates

Comment: Check the solution above using UNION ALL and LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @SOaddict Doesnt working #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124353/discussion-between-abennouna-and-soaddict).

Comment: You are all set... If you are satisfied with the answer upvote and accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need - you group each table on the date using a count and then you add values from both grouped tables:

```
DECLARE @tab1 TABLE
(
    [Date] VARCHAR(5),
    Item1 VARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @tab2 TABLE
(
    [Date] VARCHAR(5),
    Item2 VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @tab1 ( Date, Item1 ) VALUES 
('12/03','aaaa'),
('12/03','aaaa'),
('14/03','bbbb'),
('14/03','aaaa'),
('15/03','cccc')

INSERT INTO @tab2 ( Date, Item2 ) VALUES 
('11/03','aaaa'),
('12/03','aaaa'),
('13/03','bbbb'),
('14/03','aaaa'),
('15/03','cccc')


;WITH grp AS (
SELECT [Date],COUNT(*) AS Item1, 0 AS Item2 FROM @tab1 
GROUP BY [Date]

UNION

SELECT [Date],0, COUNT(*) FROM @tab2 
GROUP BY [Date] )

SELECT grp.Date, SUM(grp.Item1) AS [CountItem1], SUM(grp.Item2) AS [CountItem2] FROM grp
GROUP BY grp.Date
```